# Can I set the max-width for a responsive layout in twitter-bootstrap?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I just upgraded twitter-bootstrap from 2.0.4 to 2.2.1.  The only issue I have is that my current website now expands to the new [responsive layout](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) of 1170px and I've optimized my site around a max width of 940 pixels.  Does anyone know if it's possible to set the new responsive layout to have a max width of 940px?

My current meta tag looks like this:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the following `@media` query from your stylesheet:

```
@media (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```